# i am getting an Error "Missing comma" at line 5

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00917

I am getting an error "missing comma at line 5" from this code:

```
declare
  AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);


begin
   AGG_COLUMNS := '(''S'' || chr(38) ||''P (LT Rating)'' as SP,''CreditSights CSR'' as CSR,''FITCH (LT Rating)'' as  Fitch,''Moody||''''''||''s (LT Rating or CFR)'' as MOODY,''DBRS (LT Rating)'' as DBRS )';




execute immediate'

CREATE Global TEMPORARY TABLE temp_extRating

ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS

(select * from 
(
  select EXTRAT.Rating_ID  ,EXTRAT.AGENCY_NM  ,EXTRAT.EXT_RATING  ,EXTRAT.RBC_EQ_RATING  ,EXTRAT.EFFECTIVE_DATE 
    from RBC_P_EXT_RATING EXTRAT 
    join RBC_P_RATING Rat on 
  Rat.ID=EXTRAT.Rating_ID
  )

pivot (

  MIN(EXT_RATING) ER, 

  MIN(RBC_EQ_RATING) RER, 

  MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) ED

  FOR AGENCY_NM IN ('''||AGG_COLUMNS||''')

) 

order by Rating_ID) ';

end;
```

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: Why are you creating a temporary table on the fly? With any dynamic SQL error a good starting point is to use dbms_output to display the statement you're trying to execute; inspect that, and if necessary run it manually.

Comment: actually at that time this whole shenanigan was to be done in a procedure on the fly .... i have changed the approach since then

Answer (score 4):

If you displayed the dynamic SQL you were trying to run you'd end up with the statement:

```
...
  FOR AGENCY_NM IN ('('S' || chr(38) ||'P (LT Rating)' as SP,'CreditSights CSR' as CSR,'FITCH (LT Rating)' as  Fitch,'Moody||'''||'s (LT Rating or CFR)' as MOODY,'DBRS (LT Rating)' as DBRS )')
) 
order by Rating_ID)
```

and that IN clause is just malformed. Your `agg_column` construction has quote issues, around the concatenatin of `chr(38)` and the escaping of the two single quotes you do eventually want in `Moody''s`; it should be:

```
   AGG_COLUMNS := '''S' || chr(38) ||'P (LT Rating)'' as SP,''CreditSights CSR'' as CSR,''FITCH (LT Rating)'' as  Fitch,''Moody''''s (LT Rating or CFR)'' as MOODY,''DBRS (LT Rating)'' as DBRS';
```

You then add extra quotes, so this should be:

```
  FOR AGENCY_NM IN ('||AGG_COLUMNS||')
```

And the outermost set of parentheses around the whole select part should not be there.

```
declare
  AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
   AGG_COLUMNS := '''S' || chr(38) ||'P (LT Rating)'' as SP,''CreditSights CSR'' as CSR,''FITCH (LT Rating)'' as  Fitch,''Moody''''s (LT Rating or CFR)'' as MOODY,''DBRS (LT Rating)'' as DBRS';
   execute immediate '
CREATE Global TEMPORARY TABLE temp_extRating
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from 
(
  select EXTRAT.Rating_ID  ,EXTRAT.AGENCY_NM  ,EXTRAT.EXT_RATING  ,EXTRAT.RBC_EQ_RATING  ,EXTRAT.EFFECTIVE_DATE 
    from RBC_P_EXT_RATING EXTRAT 
    join RBC_P_RATING Rat on 
  Rat.ID=EXTRAT.Rating_ID
  )
pivot (
  MIN(EXT_RATING) ER, 
  MIN(RBC_EQ_RATING) RER, 
  MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) ED
  FOR AGENCY_NM IN ('||AGG_COLUMNS||')
) 
order by Rating_ID';
end;
/
```

I'm not sure why you have that as a separate variable, but it would be simpler to use [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) to reduce the single-quote mess.

```
   AGG_COLUMNS := q'['S]' || chr(38) || q'[P (LT Rating)' as SP,'CreditSights CSR' as CSR,'FITCH (LT Rating)' as  Fitch,'Moody''s (LT Rating or CFR)' as MOODY,'DBRS (LT Rating)' as DBRS]';
```

You can also use `set define off` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer to avoid having to concatenate the ampersand as `chr(38)`:

```
set define off
declare
  AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
   AGG_COLUMNS := q'['S&P (LT Rating)' as SP,'CreditSights CSR' as CSR,'FITCH (LT Rating)' as  Fitch,'Moody''s (LT Rating or CFR)' as MOODY,'DBRS (LT Rating)' as DBRS]';
...
```

But you don't need to use dynamic SQL at all; you seem to only have it to avoid the ampersand:

```
set define off
CREATE Global TEMPORARY TABLE temp_extRating
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from 
(
  select EXTRAT.Rating_ID  ,EXTRAT.AGENCY_NM  ,EXTRAT.EXT_RATING  ,EXTRAT.RBC_EQ_RATING  ,EXTRAT.EFFECTIVE_DATE 
    from RBC_P_EXT_RATING EXTRAT 
    join RBC_P_RATING Rat on 
  Rat.ID=EXTRAT.Rating_ID
  )
pivot (
  MIN(EXT_RATING) ER, 
  MIN(RBC_EQ_RATING) RER, 
  MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) ED
  FOR AGENCY_NM IN ('S&P (LT Rating)' as SP,'CreditSights CSR' as CSR,'FITCH (LT Rating)' as  Fitch,q'[Moody's (LT Rating or CFR)]' as MOODY,'DBRS (LT Rating)' as DBRS)
) 
order by Rating_ID;
set define on
```

Comment: I like this way , you replace `'''S' ||` with this `q'['S]'` what it called ? do you have a site explain this ?

Comment: @Moudiz - I added a link in the answer; it's referred to in the [Text literals section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) as "the alternative quoting mechanism".

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i came to use this 
select * from (
  select EXTRAT.Rating_ID  ,EXTRAT.AGENCY_NM  ,EXTRAT.EXT_RATING  ,EXTRAT.RBC_EQ_RATING  ,EXTRAT.EFFECTIVE_DATE 
    from RBC_P_EXT_RATING EXTRAT
)
pivot (
  MIN(EXT_RATING) ER, 
  MIN(RBC_EQ_RATING) RER, 
  MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) ED
  for AGENCY_NM in ('S' || chr(38) ||'P (LT Rating)' as SP,'CreditSights CSR' as CSR,'FITCH (LT Rating)' as  Fitch,'Moody''s (LT Rating or CFR)' as MOODY,'DBRS (LT Rating)' as DBRS )
) order by Rating_ID ;



But thanx for the set Define OFF  along with the alternative quoting mechanism you mentioned